# tkinter label fields for password

Tags: python, tkinter, password-hash

I am creating a tool so I can login and download things I need for work. This will be shared with others so used tkinter to scale for anyone who uses it. I want to label the fields username and password, but when I fill in

```
    pv = tkinter.StringVar(root, value='')
```

with 'password' it instead codes the field to be "*****"

What am I missing? Full widget code below:

```
def getCredentialsWidget(defaultUser):
"""Request login credentials using a GUI."""
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
root.title('Login')
uv = tkinter.StringVar(root, value=defaultUser)
pv = tkinter.StringVar(root, value='')
userEntry = tkinter.Entry(root, bd=3, width=35, textvariable=uv)
passEntry = tkinter.Entry(root, bd=3, width=35, show="*", textvariable=pv)
btnClose = tkinter.Button(root, text="OK", command=root.destroy)
userEntry.pack(padx=10, pady=5)
passEntry.pack(padx=10, pady=5)
btnClose.pack(padx=10, pady=5, side=tkinter.TOP, anchor=tkinter.NE)
root.mainloop()
return [uv.get(), pv.get()]
```

Comment: This is working as defined, since you set `show="*"` when creating the entry widget. The actual data hasn't been affected, it's only what's being shown to the user.

Comment: Apologies, what I meant to say was have titles inside the fields as labels.